# Footer issue in HTML

Tags: css, html

Here is my HTML code for footer section:

```
<footer>
    <div class="footer">
    <nav>
    <ul class="nav-list1">
    <li><img src="img/article-logo.png"  alt="img"/></li>
         </ul>
     <ul class="nav-list2">
    <li>ABOUT</li>
    <li>AUTHOURS</li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
     <hr class="hr-style" />
     <section class="footer-column">
     <div class="footer-column1">
      <img src="img/dot-net-ad.jpg" class="footer-image" alt="dot"/> 
                  <p class="footer-title">.NET Training</p>
                  <p class="footer-pgf">If you have a .NET question on a topic that 's not covered by other more specific forums.</p>
                  <a class="footer-link" href="#">ask here. ></a> 

     </div>
     <div class="footer-column2">
           <img src="img/shopify-expert-ad.jpg" class="footer-image" alt="expert"/> 
                  <p class="footer-title">Shopify Expert</p>
            </div>
       </section>
       <hr class="hr-style" />
       <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2013 Dot Net How</p>
    </div>
    </footer>
```

and, this is my styles for footer:

```
nav {
    text-align : center;
}

.footer {
    background-image : url('../img/footer-bg.jpg');
    bottom : 0;
    height : auto;
}
```

What is my mistake, and what attribute need to use?

Comment: I think i saw the same question third time.

Comment: If you really need HTML you should provide my code.

Comment: Try to use `clearfix`. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding-top` according to your picture height:

```
.footer {
    background:url(img/footer-bg.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    padding-top:100px;
}
```

Comment: when resize the window, position of footer stays fixed and seperated from wrapper.